# How to assign text into a column based on another dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df = read.table(text="group X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7
P1  H   H   H   H   H   H   H
P1  C   D   C   D   B   C   C
P1  D   C   B   A   C   D   H
P1  D   C   B   A   C   D   D
P1  C   D   C   D   B   C   D
P2  C   D   B   D   C   D   C
P2  H   H   H   H   H   H   H
P2  D   C   C   A   B   C   D
P3  C   D   C   D   B   C   C
P3  H   H   H   H   H   H   H
P3  C   D   C   D   B   C   C
P3  D   C   B   A   C   D   D", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I have another dataframe:

```
df2 = read.table(text="Group    col R   S
P1  'X2 X4 X7'  'C A D' 'D D C'
P2  'X2 X3 X4 X6'   'C C A C'   'D B D D'
P3  'X3 X5 X6 X7'   'B C D D'   'C B C C'", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to add  a column named "assign" to hold the assignment which is based on df2. For example, if df$group=="P1", then only concatenate columns in df shown in df2$col "P1" row, if all columns have the same letter "H", then assign "H" to the "assign" column; if match the string in df2$R column, assign "R"; if match the string in df2$S column, assign "S"; if not match any three cases as mentioned, then assign "U".
I have tested my script in the group "P1", but I don't know how to return the assigned value to the df and go through the loop. Appreciate any helps.
I expect the result as:

```
df = read.table(text="group 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 assign
P1 H H H H H H H H
P1 C D C D B C C S
P1 D C B A C D D U
P1 D C B A C D D R
P1 C D C D B C D U
P2 C D B D C D C S
P2 H H H H H H H H
P2 D C C A B C D R
P3 C D C D B C C S
P3 H H H H H H H H
P3 C D C D B C C S
P3 D C B A C D D R
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Unclear. *"if match the string in `df2$R` column, assign "R" "*: does that mean "if group==P1 and X2==C and X4==A and X7==D then assign 'R'"? First up, I suggest converting `df2` into a list of data.frames, so at a minimum you don't have to deal with re-parsing the nested data.frame each time. Also, WOW, reconsider what you're trying to do and restructure everything (not very helpful, I know ;-) ).

Comment: I think there was a typo in the result `df`: shouldn't `X7` be H C ___H___ D ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table` and solve your problem in three steps:

1. merge the `data.table`s
2. this is the key step, build a pattern to match later, the cool thing is that we can use a flexible number of `.SDcols` across the `by` groups in the `data.table`
3. build the `assign` variable

Here is the code:

```
# data
require(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt2 = data.table(df2)

# add col_int, a list(!) of col indices, to dt2 for each Group
dt3 = dt2[, list(col_name = strsplit(col, ' ')[[1]]), by = Group]
dt3 = dt3[, col_idx := match(col_name, names(dt))]
dt3 = dt3[, list(col_idx = list(col_idx)), by = Group]
dt2 = merge(dt2, dt3, by = 'Group')

# solution
dt = merge(x = dt,
           y = dt2,
           by = 'Group')

idx_matching_table = names(dt)

# a: using strings
dt[,
   j = pattern := {
     .SD[, do.call('paste', c(.SD)), .SDcols = strsplit(col, ' ')[[1]]]
   },
   by = list(Group, col)]

# b: using indices
dt[,
   j = pattern_2 := {
     # .SD has less cols (compared to dt), therefore find out what the integer index of col_idx in .SD is:
     col_idx_sd = match(idx_matching_table[col_idx[[1]]], names(.SD))
     .SD[, do.call('paste', c(.SD)), .SDcols = col_idx_sd]
   },
   by = list(Group, col)]
dt[, identical(pattern, pattern_2)] # TRUE

dt[, assign := 'U']
dt[pattern %like% '[H ]+H', assign := 'H']
dt[pattern == R, assign := 'R']
dt[pattern == S, assign := 'S']
```

**EDIT** I replaced `apply(.SD, 1, paste, collapse = ' ')` with `do.call('paste', c(.SD))` to avoid coercion to `matrix`.

Comment: your code is like a fresh air to me. It avoids a loop. I am just curious: if the col content in df2 is the column numbers instead of the names of columns, as a vector, how to modify your code accordingly. for example, for Group=="P1", concatenate columns 3, 5, 8 (which corresponding to X2, X4, and X7 column). The col is 3, 5, 8. I prefer to use column number instead of column names because my real data may have very long names or some names may have spaces. In order to explain what I want I used names here. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, `.SDcols` can also handle integer column indices. The `.SD` of course has different column indices compared to the full table `dt` because the `by` variables are not in it anymore. You can simply build a matching table, I will add that to the solution.